# how to disallow insecure connection to http-server npm?

Tags: security, npm, https, npm-install, httpserver

I am using below command to create secure http-server,

```
http-server -a :: -p 8081 --cors -c-1 -S -C cert.pem -K key.pem -r
```

But with below command I can able to access content,

```
curl -k https://localhost:8081/
```

How can I restrict user to not allow insecure connection to http-server ?
I just want to allow connections who verified certificate, no other connection would be allow.

PS: Here I have installed http-server using npm install http-server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "insecure".

`curl -k https://localhost:8081/` will open a **secure** HTTPS connection, the traffic is encrypted. The only thing `-k` does is to allow a connection to a certificate that you do not trust by default (usually this means that it is not signed by a CA recognized by your system/browser).

There is nothing wrong with self-signed certificates.

The trust you put on the CA is one extra layer, a layer that can help you to realize that something is wrong but that's all.

Since this is a correct HTTPS connection, you cannot restrict anything (I am not even sure what you would like to restrict? Which element would reject the connection? `curl` already does it by default and the server is happy with its certificate)

---

EDIT following comment

If you want to make sure that the **client** that is connecting is the right one then you need to take the other way round and request from your client a certificate.

In this setup, you will (usually) have mutual authentication: the client checks the certificate of the server (which in your case fails because the CA is not recognized but it does not matter) and the server asks the client to provide a certificate the server trusts.

Try searching for "SSL client certificate" (despite TLS replacing SSL, a lot of articles still use SSL wording), an example of one is https://medium.com/@sevcsik/authentication-using-https-client-certificates-3c9d270e8326

Comment: I want to allow connections who verified certificate, no other connection would be allow

Comment: @HarshilMakwana: please check the update of my answer (if I understood correctly your goal)